# How do I build platform/cts package from Android AOSP?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cts

I have downloaded the CTS package from [Android Google Gerrit](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/platform/cts) and the latest [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) but, when I try to build it, I get the following error message:

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file:
/home/scrooge/internal_git/cts/jni/Android.mk
/opt/ndk/build/core/add-application.mk:209: *** Android NDK: Aborting...
```

Comment: Try setting your NDK_PROJECT_PATH to the project directory or compile directly from command prompt from within your project folder

Comment: On the previous post, NDK_PROJECT_PATH was already pointing to the cts path name.